# group_concat and sorting in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, group-concat

Is it possible to sort the items being grouped using `group_concat` in SPARQL? I have read that this works in SQL, but dunno about SPARQL. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so,`GROUP_CONCAT` is a so-called *set function* whose arguments are multisets.

Comment: That seems like a strange limitation from a practical point of view. Is there an alternate way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: The standard doesn't provide this, but putting the query pattern in a sub query that's sorted, and then grouping in the outer query will work in some implementations, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Have a look at https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-sparql-dev/2011AprJun/0005.html

Comment: This is being considered as part of the [SPARQL 1.2 effort](https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/9).